# Rails active record query with orphans - what should I be doing here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have a model called Product which belongs to the Collection model and I want to get a grouped list of products for my index view. I can do this like so:

```
def index
  products = Product.all
  @grouped_products = products.group_by &:collection
end
```

This works fine. But now let's say that I want to make sure the collections I'm grouping by actually exist in the first place? If there are orphaned children, errors are thrown in the view. I don't want to do any presence validation in the view so how do I do it on the controller/model level?

NB: I want to allow orphaned children to be created as part of my system's design, I just want them to be omitted from certain views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join to filter the orphan Products out of the query.

```
products = Product.joins(:collection)
@grouped_productst = products.group_by &:collection
```